# I want to exclude messages during startup when setting docker-compose up results to a variable

Tags: shell, docker-compose

I am trying to run a command in docker-compose from shellscript and store the result in a variable.

```
$list_accout_aliases=$(docker-compose run --rm aws iam list-account-aliases)
```

In this case, the variable will also include the logs during container startup.

```
Creating terraform_aws_run ... done.
...
```

Any good ideas for removing the running messages from the variables?

Comment: variable assignment with a command substitution only stores `stdout` :) you see stderr on the screen **because it is not stored** in the variable

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, messages during startup seem to be stored in STDERR.

```
$ list_accout_aliases =$(docker-compose run --rm aws iam list-account-aliases 2>/dev/null)
{
    "AccountAliases": [
        "xxx"
    ]
}
```

By discarding the STDERR, we have achieved what we want to do.
I don't know if this is the best way to do it...

Comment: seems like you've added a space before = that may be completely changing your results. it is possible this is a typo in your answer. are looking to save the messages to the variable and also print it to the screen?